# HiveMQ AWS cluster not starting

Tags: amazon-web-services, mqtt, hivemq

When trying to [set up](http://www.hivemq.com/docs/hivemq/1.4.1/#hivemqdocs_ec2_cluster) a HiveMQ (1.4.1) Cluster on AWS (using the bundles `examples/cluster.xml` file) the server upstart fails with an error:

```
Unable to load class for protocol pbcast.STREAMING_STATE_TRANSFER
```

There's really no more info on why this would fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that the `examples/cluster.xml` file used the old syntax for `STREAMING_STATE_TRANSFER`, while [it should use](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/ISPN/Running+Infinispan+on+Amazon+Web+Services) just `STATE_TRANSFER` instead.

Hope that helps someone else. :)

Comment: Glad you sorted the issue out! Seems you found a regression in the example config, there will be a corrected pre-shipped config in the next release.